# Stubbing a module, its methods, and inner classes with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have a module like this that I'm trying to write unit tests for

```rb
module MyThing
  module Helpers
    def self.generate_archive
      # ...
      ::Configuration.export(arg)
    rescue ::Configuration::Error => error
      raise error
    end
  end
end
```

The `::Configuration` module can't exist in my unit testing environment for reasons that are beyond my control, so I need to stub it out.  Here's what I've come up with so far.

```rb
RSpec.describe 'MyThing' do
  it 'generates an archive' do
    configuration_stub = stub_const("::Configuration", Module.new)
    configuration_error_stub = stub_const("::Configuration::Error", Class.new)

    expect_any_instance_of(configuration_stub).to receive(:export).with("arg")
    MyThing::Helpers.generate_archive
  end
end
```

This gets me an error.

```
NoMethodError:
  Undefined method `export' for Configuration:Module
```

If I put the `configuration_stub` definition inline with the `expect_any_instance_of` like this

```rb
RSpec.describe 'MyThing' do
  it 'generates an archive' do
    configuration_error_stub = stub_const("::Configuration::Error", Class.new)

    expect_any_instance_of(stub_const("::Configuration", Module.new)).to receive(:export).with("arg")
    MyThing::Helpers.generate_archive
  end
end
```

I also get an error.

```
NameError:
  Uninitialized constant Configuration::Error
...
# --- Caused by: ---
# NoMethodError:
#   Undefined method `export' for Configuration:Module
```

Comment: Is the reason Configuration cannot exist in your unit testing environment because it has hard-coded sensitive data?

Comment: It depends on some externally-running services

Comment: Either split the configuration up into multiple environments, like Rails does, or [put the sensitive information into environment variables](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: But at any rate, I can't change it for this.

Comment: There is no sensitive information

Comment: You have hard coded configuration which is specific to a particular environment. Those techniques will fix that and solve many related problems. If you can't change it, do the best you can, but your tests are unnecessarily divorced from reality.

Answer (score 1):

`expect_any_instance_of` works on instance methods. `export` is being called as a class method.

Instead, use a normal expect on the class.

```
expect(Configuration).to receive(:export).with("arg")
```

Note: it is not necessary to write `::Configuration` in the tests. The `::` is to clarify between `MyThing::Helpers::Configuration` and `Configuration`.

Note: if you're calling methods directly on Configuration it should probably be a Class not a Module.

Note: instead of calling methods on a class, consider using a Configuration object. `App.config.export` where `App.config` returns the default Configuration object. This is more flexible.

The problem with that is RSpec will verify that `Configuration.export` exists. It doesn't. You could turn off verification, or you could make a real class to test with.

```
  before {
    stub_const(
      "Configuration",
      Class.new do
        def self.export(*args)
        end
      end
    )
  }

  it 'exports' do
    expect(Configuration).to receive(:export).with("arg")
    Configuration.export("arg")
  end
```

You could write a stub Configuration module for testing only and put it into spec/support, but your tests are increasingly divorced from reality.

The real problem is your project should have a real Configuration class!

I'm going to guess the real Configuration contains production information which cannot be checked into the repository. This is a common anti-pattern. The Configuration module should hide the details of where the configuration values are coming from. There should be independent development, test, and production configurations. There are many ways of doing this, the most common are to use environment specific config files, or to [store environment specific config values in environment variables](https://12factor.net/config).

---

While you could mock the `Configuration::Error` exception, there should be no reason `Configuration::Error` cannot exist in your test environment. Add it and simulate an error like so:

```
  context 'when Configuration.export raises an error'
    before {
      allow(Configuration).to receive(:export).and_raise(Configuration::Error)
    }

    it 'does whatever its supposed to do' do
    end
  end
```